# M1. Finding all parent (configurable) products that have not children (simple) products set

Tags: configurable-product

How can I find `all parent (configurable) products that have no children (simple) products linked`. these products are not logical as they can never be sold.

Answer (score 0):

Run Mysql query

```
Select entity_id,type_id,sku,created_at FROM `catalog_product_entity` where entity_id  not in (SELECT parent_id FROM `catalog_product_super_link`) and type_id='configurable'
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work to get all the configurable products without any child (simple product) assigned to it.

```
Select entity_id,type_id,sku,created_at FROM `catalog_product_entity` where entity_id  not in (SELECT parent_id FROM `catalog_product_relation`) and type_id='configurable'
```